# CaptainCasa framework: TOUCHSIGNATURE component output as image/png data

Tags: jsp, captaincasa

Do we have the option to get TOUCHSIGNATURE output as image/png ? We want to be able to embed the signature in different documents (pdf, html, markdown, etc...) and a png image will give us the most flexibility.

It should be relatively simple to implement on the frontend, since html canvas is used.

```
canvasElement.toDataUrl()
```

It will save us allot of hassle trying to convert those pixel coordinates to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a class SignatureImageCreator (package org.eclnt.util.image) which exactly does this job.

Just call its method:

```
public static byte[] createPNGFromSignature(String coordinatesCSV)
```

The result is a byte-array representing the PNG-image.